# how to update a module-defined view?

Tags: views, 7

In D6, I have a custom module that I've developed. It has a view.

I've made some changes to the view in the module code, and I wanted those changes to go live on the site. I've clear the cache, but I don't see my changes.  What should I do,  disable, revert, delete?

Comment: This is a question asked by user1359,  http://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/9015/how-to-update-a-module-defined-view,  however he delete the question before I could post my answer.  I still believe its a valid question.  I've edited the description of the question a little bit.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1 -  if its a default view,  you should not be able to delete it.  You should only have the option to *Enable* or *Disable* it.  If the enabled view is alter then you only have the option to *Revert*.

2 - An unaltered default views are not stored in the views_view table of the database (however they are stored in the cache_views table).   If you alter the view,  they are *now* stored in the views_view table.

So,  if you have a unaltered default view and you make changes to it in the code, then the changes will be visible once you clear the cache.   If you have an alter default view, you must revert it for it to match the code in your module.